# Contrast & brightness of images using IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage

Please have a look at the following code

```
using namespace cv;
double alpha = 1.6;
int beta = 50;
int i = 0;
IplImage* input_img = cvLoadImage("c:\\Moori.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
IplImage* imageGray = cvCreateImage(cvSize(input_img->width, input_img->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    for( int y = 0; y < input_img->height; y++ )
    { 
        for( int x = 0; x < input_img->width; x++ )
        { 

            i = y * imageGray->width + x;
            imageGray->imageData[i] = (alpha * input_img->imageData[i]) + beta;
        }
    }
cvNamedWindow("Image IplImage", 1);
cvShowImage("Image IplImage", imageGray);
waitKey();
cvReleaseImage(&imageGray);
cvReleaseImage(&input_img);
cvDestroyWindow("Image IplImage");
```

when I run this code, it shows an image with many dark pixels.
But, when i run the code, which is available at:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html
it works fine. I want to do by IplImage. Please help

Answer (score 1):

saturate_cast is for c++. 
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html

Finally, I have solved this problem.

```
IplImage* img;
cvNamedWindow("Display");
while(true)
{
    img = cvLoadImage("Moori.jpg");
    CvScalar brVal = cvScalarAll(abs(10.0));
    cvAddS(img, brVal, img, NULL);
    IplImage *pTempImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, img->nChannels);
    cvSet( pTempImg, cvScalarAll(1), NULL );
    double scale = 1.5;
    cvMul(img, pTempImg, img, scale);
    cvReleaseImage(&pTempImg);
    cvShowImage("Display", img);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    int c=cvWaitKey(10);              
    if(c==27) break;
}
cvDestroyWindow("Display");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ I am not sure why anybody would want to use IplImage. But your problem is this line

```
 imageGray->imageData[i] = (alpha * input_img->imageData[i]) + beta;
```

It can overflow. Also imageData is a char*, and a char may be signed or unsigned, you need to make it unsigned. You need use [saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#saturate-cast) to prevent overflow, and a cast to get rid of the signed char:

```
imageGray->imageData[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>((alpha * static_cast<uchar>(input_img->imageData[i])) + beta);
```

You can use this little program to see what is going on:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <vector>       // std::vector
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double alpha = 1.6;
    int beta = 50;

    std::vector<uchar> z;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 255; ++i)
        z.push_back(i);

    char* zp = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&z[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 255; ++i)
        std::cout << i << " -> " << int(cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * static_cast<uchar>(zp[i]) + beta))  << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I already tried to use saturate_cast<uchar>, but it gives very little effect. It makes dark pixels (error) more dark. The problem is that some pixel values become NULL.

Comment: OK, I forgot that imageData is a char* (which can be signed (platform dependent)) and this will mess things up. I have edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: I added static_cast<uchar>(input_img->imageData[i]), but result is same. I also tried same code on different images, but result was same. Please see the image from the following link: http://sl.avouch.org/files/changed_image.jpg

Comment: Did you include the saturate_cast as well (it is essential)? This works fine for me in VS2012. Could you add your modified code to the end of your question? Also, what platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to **cast** the image values to `uchar`. You have to **reinterpret** the values as `uchar`. It Means you have to assume that the data bits actually represent an `unsigned char`, regardless of the type of pointer. It can be done as follows:

```
uchar* ptr = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(imageGray->imageData);
ptr[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * ptr[i] + beta);
```

Comment: Am I correct? uchar* Imgptr = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(input_img->imageData);    imageGray->imageData[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * Imgptr[i]) + beta;   Result is same like previous. I am using VS2010.

Comment: @IRFAN... No, you have to access data using `Imgptr` like this: `Imgptr[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * Imgptr[i] + beta);`

Comment: like this...?: uchar* Imgptr = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(imageGray->imageData);
   Imgptr[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * input_img->imageData[i]) + beta;
   imageGray->imageData = (char*)Imgptr;

Comment: @IRFAN... not like this. `Imgptr` and `imageGray->imageData` are pointing to same memory location. Just dont use `imageGray->imageData` in any calculations. The last statement is not required and it doesn't do anything. Also, place `beta` inside the bracket as I have mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Result is same....    uchar* Imgptr = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(imageGray->imageData);
   Imgptr[i] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * input_img->imageData[i] + beta);

Comment: @IRFAN... *i am banging my head*... why are you still using `imageData` directly again and again? Use Imgptr in **all** the calculations.

Comment: @sgar... if i use only Imgptr, I get nothing. no image.. Imgptr[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * Imgptr[i] + beta);    because i am reading image by IplImage* input_img....